# get the month and year of the given date field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the field date_start field which is a date datatype. I want to get the month and year of the field date_start and check the month is in given date month '2021-02-01'.

```
$meeting_ids=DB::table('meeting_dump')
    ->Where(DB::raw(date('m-y',strtotime('meeting_dump.date_start'))),'=',date("m-y", strtotime($dates_between[0])))
    ->pluck('meeting_dump.parent_id')
    ->toArray();
```

given date is `2021-02-01` and meeting start date is `2021-02-01`, `2021-01-05` need to pick the `parent_id` for `2021-02-01`

Comment: use `->whereMonth('date_start', '=', '02')->whereYear('start_date', '=', '2021')` for february 2021

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Carbon:

```
(new Carbon('2021-02-01'))->format("m-y") //this will yield 02-21
```

You can do the same for your date field.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I would suggest to create date range of month start and month end from your input date instead of formatting the dates on fly

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse("2021-02-01");
$start = $date->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end = $date->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And in query builder use between filter the benefit of this approach is your query remains [**sargable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) means if there is an index added on this column it will use that index but if you perform formatting on your date column then index will get ignored

```
$meeting_ids= DB::table('meeting_dump')
                ->whereBetween('date_start', [$start, $end])
                ->pluck('parent_id')
                ->toArray();
```